# r.js exclude non-build layer files when using 'dir' and 'modules'

Tags: requirejs, r.js

My project structure is pretty complex and it is a mix of jsp/js/css files.

in build.js i use 'dir' and 'modules', output folder contains everything starting at baseUrl, it is thousands of files and folders but i need only few build layer files that is specified in 'modules' directive,

is there a way to not to copy non-build layer files into 'dir' folder?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you could try removeCombined option. See https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L349

Below is a snippet from above URL

```
//If set to true, any files that were combined into a build bundle will be
//removed from the output folder.
removeCombined: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
skipDirOptimize: true
```

to exclude all non-build layer files. r.js will then only optimize (and copy) the build layers (`modules` section of your build script).

See [the example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L95) file from the documentation.